# How do I solve the Key Error while using the pandas library?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

if I use the following code I get an Error Message.
Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

```
    print(data_wald_nan)
    r = [scipy.stats.pearsonr(x=data_wald_nan["vaxx_rate"], y=data_wald_nan[independend_variable])]
    print()
    y = data_wald_nan["vaxx_rate"]
    x = data_wald_nan[independend_variable]
    fig = sns.scatterplot(data=data_wald_nan, y="vaxx_rate", x=independend_variable, c = colors)
    fig.set_title( "Waldorfschools per million capitas and \n vaccination rate "
                                             "in countries \n (correlation-coefficient: " + str(r) +
                 ")", weight="bold")
    fig.set_ylabel("Vaccination Rate in %")
    fig.set_xlabel("Share of Waldorfschools per million capitas")
    for line in range(0, data_wald_nan.shape[0]):
        fig.text(data_wald_nan.Wald_Schools_per_Mln_People[line] + 0.01, data_wald_nan.vaxx_rate[line],
                data_wald_nan.Country[line], horizontalalignment='left',
                size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')
    fig.set_ylim(ymin=20, ymax=100)
    fig.set_xlim(xmin=0,xmax=9)
    plt.grid(visible=True, color="grey", linestyle="-", linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.2)
    plt.show()
```

This is the error message:

```
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 2131, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 2140, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

EDIT (The full Errorcode)
It says I have to add more text to this question but I dont know what to type:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\david\OneDrive\Dokumente\Dokumente\uni\CSS\FCSS\data\scatter.py", line 55, in <module>
    scatter("Wald_Schools_per_Mln_People")
  File "C:\Users\david\OneDrive\Dokumente\Dokumente\uni\CSS\FCSS\data\scatter.py", line 38, in scatter
    fig.text(data_wald_nan.Wald_Schools_per_Mln_People[line] + 0.01, data_wald_nan.vaxx_rate[line],
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 942, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1051, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: That error usually means that the column name you are trying to access does not exist. Can you show us the full error message please?

Comment: Try changing `fig.text(data_wald_nan.Wald_Schools_per_Mln_People[line] + 0.01...` to `fig.text(data_wald_nan.Wald_Schools_per_Mln_People.iloc[line] + 0.01...`

Comment: @DPM I added the full errorcode! thank you!

Comment: It seems like you want to access the value of a row for a given column, the proper way to do it is, like @richardec said, using .iloc[line]

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code:

```
fig.text(data_wald_nan.Wald_Schools_per_Mln_People[line] + 0.01...
```

to

```
fig.text(data_wald_nan.Wald_Schools_per_Mln_People.iloc[line] + 0.01...
```